# Why is Apple creating some of their image assets the way they are on apple.com?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, jpeg

If you visit the new iPhone 12 page, there are several image sequences (mostly JPG sequences) that use image assets where the image itself is built out of blocks of 248px x 8px.

[image]

The image sequence consists of assets like this:

[image]

They use canvases and probably piece together the parts with JS. But why are they doing it like this?
The page can be found here: https://www.apple.com/iphone-12-pro/

Comment: It's not a design question. They have gone this route probably because of some technical advantages. I'd like to understand these.

Comment: "Design decisions" include the technical implementation. What ever are the reasons, we can't know their motivation to favor a specific technique, unless someone working at Apple sees your question ...

Comment: I've just visited the page, and i think they are using this kind of pictures to implement a nice scrolling animation effects for each section, it has something to do with the scrolling if you are not sure about it. Then you can just go and keep scrolling until you reach that section where there are some iphones and the shinning effect animate synchroniously with the scrollbar.

Comment: Yes, it must be because of the animations but you mostly see image sequence animations with regular images. So I was wondering if in regards to JPG compression this way you might receive a smaller image or something similar.

Comment: Given [this file](https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/iphone-12-pro/2020/e70ffbd8-50f1-40f3-ac36-0f03a15ac314/anim/charge/large/flow/flow_manifest.json) I'd say these images are atlas that only contain the diffs between each frame (a bit like MJPEG does). Also: https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/575heg/understanding_apples_web_animations/

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the fact that large sized and high-resolution images can drastically reduce the page load speed. And there are tons of them on apple's product pages.

So slicing images this way allows the browser to download multiple pieces of the image in parallel instead of one big piece. In consequence, it takes less time to display the same image.

Comment: But one image still represents one frame of the animation. So one image is not containing several frames.

Comment: Oh yes i see, then i have no clue :(